# Generate file with corrupted NTFS Master File Table entry in code

Tags: windows, file, ntfs

Our software has somehow created a corrupt file at a customer site, but it is proving impossible to reproduce or isolate the error. Every test we can think of just works. The rest of the system is fine, this is affecting only a single file (which strongly implicates a coding error). Deleting the file recovers the system with no apparent ill effects.

The customer has returned the computer:

- Attempting to copy or open the file in a text editor generates: `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`
- Attempting to read file with a hex editor (eg. [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/)) generates `File stream error.`
- Running `chkdsk /V` on the NTFS volume generates the diagnostic message `FILE first allocation unit is not valid. The entry will be truncated.`

For testing, is it possible to create a corrupt file eg. with an invalid `first allocation unit` entry in the NTFS Master File Table? Any language will do but ideally C/C++, C# or Delphi code.

**UPDATE**

After running `chkdsk /F` on the volume, the files are now fixed. The following entry appear in the Windows > Application events log:

\PATH\CORRUPTED-FILE.ini  first allocation unit is not valid. The entry will be truncated.

Comment: It's Windows API who creates and writes to files in Delphi (if you do it common way). This sounds more like a hardware failure.

Comment: Possibly, though this has happened on two separate occasions (months apart and never in the lab). You could have a point if we are using cheap hard disks...need to check on that.

Comment: Looks from what you say like the file is an .Ini file.  Are you writing it using a TIniFile or a TMemIniFile?

Comment: This could be effect of power cut, loose cables, faulty RAM. There is practically no chance to do this kind of damage form user mode unintentionally. You would have to use direct write bypasing ntfs kernel module.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes, actually `TMemIniFile`. Could that be relevant?

Comment: Well, TMemIniFile only touches the file on disk via a TStringList in `UpdateFile()`, which ought to be reliable enough that it would be very unlikely to be the cause - it's not even as if the StringList would have a file handle open for any length of time.  However, you could try reproducing the problem by continually writing differently sized stringlists to a file.

Comment: Btw googling 'deliberately corrupt mft' comes up with this, amongst others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296752/intentionally-corrupt-the-file-system

Comment: @MartynA: Thanks, will look into that linked question. Not sure the accepted answer is very good, though. I'm also looking at the TStringList::SaveToFile as an alternative to TMemIniFile and will try your suggestion of continuously writing to a file and see what happens.